Suppress stdout of a coroutine without affecting other coroutines in python
import asyncio
import contextlib
import os

async def my_coroutine():
    with open(os.devnull, 'w') as f, contextlib.redirect_stdout(f):
        print("This will not be printed")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("This will be printed")

async def my_coroutine2():
    print("This will be printed from 2")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(
        my_coroutine(),
        my_coroutine2()
    )

asyncio.run(main())

In the above case, the output will be
This will be printed

Is there a way to print
This will be printed from 2
This will be printed

That means I want to suppress the stdout of only my_coroutine without affecting my_coroutine2

Maybe a clever workaround exists, but what you want to do is not possible to achieve directly, because a single process has only one stdout (file descriptor #1). Even the docs for contextlib.redirect_stdout warns about a "global side-effect".

@VPfB  yes -  but inside a Python process, the stdout is acessible via a unique point  - sys.stdout - which is a modifiable value. From the O.S. point of view, there is a unique "stdout" file, but for each call that would print something to it, you have a chance to set the context you want, with simple Python code, which is very well stated as the O.P.'s goal.

Yes. Feasible -
What happens is that any "global" effect, even if thread-safe, in  a sense it will affect a single thread, won't work with concurrent asyncio tasks - since those run in the same thread.
For that matter, the language introduced "contextvars" which are value containers which can actually present a unique value for the same asyncio task (or the same "asyncio task-tree" when dealing with tasks that are created as subtasks of another), in the same way "threading.local" namespaces are unique per thread.
What is needed is to replace the stdout not by a simple stream, as  contextlib.redirect_stdout(f): when used with the docs example does, but with a "smart" stream which will read a contextvar, and know whether to use the original stdout value, or a "/dev/null" stream or logfile of choice.
As it is, one can even make use of redirect_stdout  itself, as it will take care of proper patching and restoring its values (otherwise one would need to manually resort patching sys.__stdout__ or other inner places)
That said, you will need a stream-like class which will take context information into account . The redirect of the stdout itself has to take place in an outer level (the root task for both the tasks you want to print and those you will leave as they are) - and we have to write a mechanism to set the contextvar value in the output-supressed function. That can be made either with using the  context-manager (with statement) mechanism, or even with a decorator. New tasks are always run in a new context by default - so we don't have to worry about the cumbersome contextvars.copy_context().run()   approaches to run a call in a new context, which is required with synchronous code.
import asyncio
import contextlib
import os

import sys
import contextvars


_REDIRECT_STDOUT = contextvars.ContextVar("_REDIRECT_STDOUT", default=False)


class Redirector:
    def __init__(self, output=None):
        if output is None:
            output = open("/dev/null", "wt")
        self.output = output
        self.original_stdout = sys.__stdout__

    @property
    def current_stdout(self, *args, **kw):
        return self.output if _REDIRECT_STDOUT.get() else self.original_stdout

    def write(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.current_stdout.write(*args, **kwargs)

    def flush(self):
        return self.current_stdout.flush()

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        # just to avoid errors - in case one goes calling
        # "close", "isatty", "encoding", etc ...
        return getattr(self.original_stdout, attr)


def supress_output(async_func):
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        _REDIRECT_STDOUT.set(True)
        return await async_func(*args, **kwargs)
        # no need to restore _REDIRECT_STDOUT: as an async task ends, so does
        # the context in which it was executed
    return wrapper

@supress_output
async def my_coroutine():
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    print("This will not be printed")
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    print("This will not be printed either")
    print("printed to stderr, just so we are sure 'my_couroutine' run correctly", file=sys.stderr)

async def my_coroutine2():
    await asyncio.sleep(0.25)
    print("This will be printed from 2")
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    print("This will be printed from 2")

async def main():
    with contextlib.redirect_stdout(Redirector()):
        await asyncio.gather(
            my_coroutine(),
            my_coroutine2()
        )

asyncio.run(main())

as you can see, I opted for using supress_output as a decorator here - but if you want a context manager, it is as simple as something that will set the context-variable on __enter__ and restore it on __exit__:
...
# declaration of the _REDIRECT_STDOUT
# and Redirector class as above
...

class SupressOutput:
    def __enter__(self):
        self.original = _REDIRECT_STDOUT.get()
        _REDIRECT_STDOUT.set(True)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args, **kw):
        _REDIRECT_STDOUT.set(self.original)

async def my_coroutine():
    with SupressOutput():
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
        print("This will not be printed")
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
        print("This will not be printed either")
    print("This is printed out normally!")
...

# patching with `redirect_stdout` in "main" as in the snippet above.
...
...

